# How does PostgreSQL's citext type affect string comparisons made using LOWER()?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, citext

The impetus for my question is that I had hoped that PostgreSQL would behave consistently when selecting from `citext` columns, regardless of whether or not the string to be matched is wrapped in one or more instances of `lower()` (any such wrapping is beyond my control). That appears not to be the case. (Of course, it is entirely possible that my tests are invalid or I am misunderstanding fundamental concepts.)

## Steps to Reproduce Testing Scenario

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;
CREATE TABLE users (id int, email citext);
INSERT INTO users(id, email) VALUES
  (1, 'USER@example.com');
```

## Tests

As expected when using the `citext` type, the lowercase variant yields a result:

```
# select * from users where email = 'user@example.com';
 id |      email
----+------------------
  1 | USER@example.com
(1 row)
```

Changing the `=` operator to `like` yields a result:

```
select * from users where email like lower('user@example.com');
 id |      email
----+------------------
  1 | USER@example.com
(1 row)
```

As does the "inverse":

```
# select * from users where lower(email) = 'user@example.com';
 id |      email
----+------------------
  1 | USER@example.com
(1 row)
```

As does wrapping both values in `lower()`:

```
# select * from users where lower(email) = lower('user@example.com');
 id |      email
----+------------------
  1 | USER@example.com
(1 row)
```

## My Question

Why then does the following query not return a result in this instance?

```
# select * from users where email = lower('user@example.com');
 id | email
----+-------
(0 rows)
```

The [manual says of the `citext` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html):

> Essentially, it internally calls lower when comparing values.

The operative word seems to be "essentially"; this statement implies the following, which does yield a result:

```
select * from users where lower(email) = lower(lower('user@example.com'));
 id |      email
----+------------------
  1 | USER@example.com
(1 row)
```

Might this be related to the following caveat in the `Limitations` section of the above-cited document?

> citext's case-folding behavior depends on the LC_CTYPE setting of your database.

```
# SHOW LC_CTYPE;
  lc_ctype
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8
(1 row)
```

Any explanation in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tldr; when comparing case insensitive and sensitive things for equality, you have to be explicit. `text` is explicitly case-sensitive; `citext` is explicitly case-insensitive. You *should* provide a cast for both sides and be explicit**

A few things about `lower()`

- `lower()` is typed
- When it's argument are `text`, it always returns `text`

A few other points

- When you do a comparison with a literal, the type isn't known (it's explicitly `unknown` internally).
- Operators are functions.
- Functions coerce the types in PostgreSQL in runtime.

In this case types are as follows, with description

```
-- text = unknown
-- unknown promoted to text, this has nothing to do with citext
lower(email) = 'user@example.com';

-- text = text
-- this has nothing to do with citext
lower(email) = lower('user@example.com');

-- text = text
-- this has nothing to do with citext    
lower(email) = lower(lower('user@example.com'));

-- citext LIKE text
-- LIKE is smart `operator ~~(citext,text)` via `texticlike`
-- WORKS
email like lower('user@example.com');

-- citext = unknown
-- unknown promoted to citext, there is an `operator =(citext,citext)`
-- WORKS
email = 'user@example.com';

-- citext = text
-- citext promoted to text, there is no `operator =(citext,text)`
-- FAILS
email = lower('user@example.com');
```

In summary, there is an `operator =(citext,citext)`. So you can

```
email = lower('user@example.com')::citext;
```

If you want, or you can define your own operator that sets `=` to the case insensitive route rather than the case sensitive route. I find that to be horrible practice though, I'll always cast.

Comment: An excellent and thorough response! Thank you, Evan! I really appreciate your time and expertise.